# How to propagate the null value of a navigation property, when grouping by a property of a nullable navigation property?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Let's say we have these entities in EfCore...

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    // ... omitted for brevity
    public int? NavigationPropertyId { get; set; }
    public NavigationProperty? NavigationProperty { get; set; }
    // ... omitted for brevity
}

public class NavigationProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnotherNavigationPropertyId { get; set; }
    // ... omitted for brevity
}
```

...and we want to get the *average* `Rate` of `Entities` that have the same `AnotherNavigationProperty`.

The efcore query I attempted throws a "System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value".

```
from entity in _context.Entities
group entity by entity.NavigationProperty.AnotherNavigationPropertyId 
    into entitiesByAnotherNavigationProperty
orderby entitiesByAnotherNavigationProperty.Key
select new 
{
    AnotherNavigationPropertyId = entitiesByAnotherNavigationProperty.Key,
    AverageRate = entitiesByAnotherNavigationProperty.Average(a => a.Rate)
}
```

which I know is successfully translated by EfCore as `ToQueryString()` on the query returns

```
SELECT [p].[AnotherNavigationPropertyId], AVG([a].[Rate]) AS [AverageRate]
FROM [Entities] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [NavigationProperties] AS [p] ON [a].[NavigationPropertyId] = [p].[Id]
GROUP BY [p].[AnotherNavigationPropertyId]
ORDER BY [p].[AnotherNavigationPropertyId]
```

Which correctly returns the results that I need when ran on the database

How can I hint EfCore to propagate the null navigation property? (As expression trees cannot contain the null propagating `?.` operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the difference between C# and SQL null semantics.

In SQL query every value can be `null` even though the source column does not allow `null`. In fact there are no such thing like nullable or not nullable type, just `not null` constraint. While in LINQ query the nullability is determined by the static type of the property.

Shortly, we have conflict between CLR and SQL query value type. In order to resolve it, you have to let CLR know that the expression type actually is nullable, even though its inferred CLR type is not. Since `?.` is not allowed in expression trees, you have to use `cast` operator for that. The only drawback is that you need to know the exact property type (cannot use the normal type inference).

With that being said, in the sample query from the question it's a matter of adding `int?` cast here

```cs
group entity by (int?)entity.NavigationProperty.AnotherNavigationPropertyId
```